# HTML dropwndown horizontal alignment not worked in IE10

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Below code Woks fine in previous versions of `IE10`and all other browsers.

```
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit" value="Test1"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit" value="Test2"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit" value="Test3"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit" value="Test4"  />
```

IN `IE10 browser raidion button` displayed in one by one , not in single row.

I want to display the all radio button items in single row.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will definitely work on IE 10.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    input[type="radio"]{float:left;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you better to try this one, because you used `display: inherit`, which means it will positioned relative to the parent element.

```
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit;float:left;width:15px;" value="Test1"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit;float:left;width:15px;" value="Test2"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit;float:left;width:15px;" value="Test3"  />
<input type="radio"  name="RBLSample" style="display:inherit;float:left;width:15px;" value="Test4"  />
```